# Reading from file error in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, filereader

I am trying to read from a file and input each line into a ArrayList. I have my file in the same folder as the main java file. There are no spelling errors in the file names. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("lab02in.txt"));
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        countries.add(line);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println("Printing New list after adding from file");
    displayCountries(countries);
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: lab02in.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at lab2.Lab2.main(Lab2.java:50)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: try use the full path and remember to replace "\" with "\\"

Comment: What is wrong is that the application can't find your file or cannot read from it.  Have you checked that both of those conditions do not prohibit your application from executing successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running your Java program correctly, then your current directory is the directory above `lab2`.  Then you state that the file is in the same directory as your Java source code.  The code is looking in the current directory, not the source code directory, so it didn't find your file.

Try one of the following:

1. Move your text file to the current directory (above `lab2`).  This is preferred, because source code and resources shouldn't mix.  OR
2. Prepend `lab2/` to your relative pathname when creating the `FileReader`.

Code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("lab02/lab02in.txt"));
```

Comment: I just moved the .txt file into the main directory like option 1. and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your current working directory for the VM is different from the directory where your file is. If the file `lab02in.txt` is static and relative to the class (i.e. in the same directory) you can (and should) load it with `getResourceAsStream`. Otherwise you need to specify the path.

Answer (score 0):

Check System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
This should give you some idea where its looking for the file.